# TikZ/pgf: When using the `graphdrawing` library, can I draw an edge from a node, to the "edge node" of an edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's the working example I have been playing with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

    \tikz [spring layout, node distance=25mm]
    {
        \node (a) {a};
        \node (b) {b};
        \node (c) {c};

        \draw 
        (a) edge[->] (b)
        (b) edge[->] (c)
        (c) edge[->] (b.north);
    }

\end{document}
```

I would like the edge from `c` to go to to the middle of the edge between `a` and `b`, however, my current attempt which tries to use `b.north`, does nothing -- it doesn't even draw an edge from `c` to anywhere else. Is there a way I can refer to "edge node" of an edge, in order to draw an edge to it?

Comment: @cfr I don't think `rounded corners` is there in this example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post that comment on your other question about the decorations getting messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\begin{document}
\tikz[spring layout, node distance=25mm,>=latex']{
    \node (a) {a};
    \node[cut policy=none] (x) {};
    \node (b) {b};
    \node (c) {c};
    \draw 
      (a) edge (x)
      (x) edge[->] (b)
      (b) edge[->] (c)
      (c) edge[->] (x);
}
\end{document}
```

or shorter

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows}
\usegdlibrary{force}

\begin{document}
\tikz[spring layout, node distance=25mm,>=latex']
  \graph{a--x[as=, cut policy=none]->b->c, c->x};
\end{document}
```

[image]